# How to convert preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a project to php 5.6/7 compatibility.
And I'm having issues with this function below.

Original function code:

```
function parsetemplate($template, $array) {
    return preg_replace('#\{([a-z0-9\-_]*?)\}#Ssie', '( ( isset($array[\'\1\']) ) ? $array[\'\1\'] : \'\' );', $template);
}
```

My attempt to change from `preg_replace()` to `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
function parsetemplate($template, $array) {
    return preg_replace_callback('#\{([a-z0-9\-_]*?)\}#Ssie', '( ( isset($array[\'\1\']) ) ? $array[\'\1\'] : \'\' );', $template);
}
```

I tried several ways, but none seems to work for me, anyone can help me?

Comment: show the input data which causes issue

Comment: So: 1) Look into the manual about [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) 2) Remove the deprecated modifier `e` and replace your replacement with an anonymous function as callback (Second argument). 3) Now your matches will be in an array as the first argument of your function. 4) Since you need `$array` in your callback function, but it would be out of scope you need to pass it by `use()`. So you would end up with something like this:

Comment: `function parsetemplate($template, $array) {
    return preg_replace_callback('#\{([a-z0-9\-_]*?)\}#Ssi', function($m)use($array){
        return isset($array[$m[1]]) ? $array[$m[1]] : ""; 
    }, $template);
}`

Comment: thanks, works like a charm